# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/jpa/exceptions/NoPersistenceXmlException

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, jpa-2.0, dao

I'm trying to use Google AppEngine to build a rest-full server.
I'm used to create ones with springframework + jpa but I've some problem when I lunch my app in debug.
I've configured my project in this way:

domain like this

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
.......
```

dao like this

```
    public interface UserDAO extends JpaDao<User> {

.....
```

daoImpl like this

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class WineDAOImpl extends AbstractJpaDao<Wine> implements WineDAO {


    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "transactions-optional")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private final static Set<Class<?>> dataTypes = new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(new Class<?>[] { Wine.class }));


    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

.....
```

service

```
 public interface UserService {
.....
```

service Impl

```
@Service("UserService")
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    protected UserDAO userDAO;
.....
```

and this is my mvc-dispatcher-servlet

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">


    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean"
        lazy-init="true">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="transactions-optional" />
    </bean>

    <bean name="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="xx.xxx.xxxxxx.service"
        scoped-proxy="interfaces" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="xx.xxx.xxxxxx"
        scoped-proxy="interfaces" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="xx.xxx.xxxxxx.dao"
        scoped-proxy="interfaces" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and in the end my percistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <persistence-unit name="transactions-optional">
        <provider>org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>xx.xxxxx.xxxxxx.domain.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalRead" value="true" />
            <property name="datanucleus.NontransactionalWrite" value="true" />
            <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="appengine" />
            <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency"
                value="EVENTUAL" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="5000" />
            <property name="datanucleus.datastoreWriteTimeout" value="10000" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

But when I try to debug my code I receive this error

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting bean property 'entityManagerFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/jpa/exceptions/NoPersistenceXmlException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:247)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticServerInstanceHolder.java:26)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractServer.startup(AbstractServer.java:80)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Servers.startup(Servers.java:78)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:237)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:509)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1093)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/jpa/exceptions/NoPersistenceXmlException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/datanucleus/jpa/exceptions/NoPersistenceXmlException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createFactory(Persistence.java:160)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:112)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$6.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1504)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.datanucleus.jpa.exceptions.NoPersistenceXmlException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:215)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 54 more
```

Anybody help me?

Comment: percistence.xml. Is the real filename? The correct is persistence.xml

Comment: No sorry, It's a stupid mistake: my file is persistence.xml

Comment: what is the version of your datanucleos jar?

Comment: datanucleos-core-3.1.3